# How to use org-mode file as google code description?

Tags: org-mode, google-code, wiki-markup

My projects host on Google Code and I use emacs to edit project files. So the readme file is org-mode file.

In GitHub it can use org-mode file as project's description. But in Google Code, the description is format at Wiki markup.

I try to convert org-mode file to wiki markup use http://labs.seapine.com/htmltowiki.cgi. But it looks bad.( http://code.google.com/p/translate-emacs-toolkit/ )

So my question is "Did anyone encounter the same problem?" and "How do you solve?".

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why it works on GitHub is because of the package [org-ruby](https://github.com/bdewey/org-ruby) written by Brian Dewey.  GitHub has somehow agreed to run this bit of ruby code for parsing org-mode files on their servers.  You would likely need to convince Google of the same, if you wanted to use on Google Code.

As far as exporting org-mode directly to wiki markup, I don't know of any current projects.  There are a few plugins mentioned for other bits of code for converting to wiki-like syntax on the [Org Blogs and Wikis](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-blog-wiki.html) page.

Comment: Thanks. Your information is usefull. I am not familiar with ruby. Is there similar one in python? I will learn ruby soon.

Comment: Not that I know of, but I've not researched it extensively.